# Codefights Loop tunel Q2

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am unable to pass the hidden tests for this question. can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

The error message is:

> "Execution time limit exceeded on test 7: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input."

My code:

```
def countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r):
    c=0
    for i in range(l,r+1):
        for j in range(l,i+1):
            if(i+j==n):
                c+=1
    return(c)
```

Comment: What inputs are you giving it?..

Comment: Can you provide the link for this question

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is :

> Given integers n, l and r, find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two >integers A and B such that l ≤ A ≤ B ≤ r.

Adding 2 for loops in your code might have increase the time complexity of your code as it is a naive approach form your side. You should have try this :

```
def countSumOfTwoRepresentations(n,l,r):
    result = 0
    for a in range(1,r+1):
        b = n - a
        if(b >= l and b <= r and b >= a):
            result+=1
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

In this repository You can find Codefights Arcade Solutions

https://github.com/tigranv/Code_Fights_Solutions

```
int countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(int n, int l, int r) {

    int count = 0;

    for(int i = l; i<=r; i++)
    {
      for(int j = i; j<=r&&n-j>=l; j++)
    {
     if(i+j == n)  count++;
    }  

    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm new here, hope soon I will do everything as it should